# Django: can not create multiple model objects with one-to-one relation with one common model

Tags: django, django-models

I have two models that extend `auth.models.User` of django with `one-to-one` relation between model and the user. I want to create objects of  either one of those two, using a form.

two models are :

```py
class Worker(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_worker(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Worker.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_worker(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.worker.save()

class Employer(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def create_user_employer(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Employer.objects.create(user=instance)

    @receiver(post_save, sender=User)
    def save_user_employer(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        instance.employer.save()
```

And I have a creator view function as:

```py
def worker_sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WorkerSignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.employer = None
            user.worker = Worker()
            user.worker.address= form.cleaned_data.get('address')
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = WorkerSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/workersignup.html', {'form': form})
```

I expect to have a `user` and a `worker` in my database, but It creates both `Worker` and `Employer` objects.

p.s.
My form class is:

```py
class WorkerSignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=400)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
```

Answer (score 0):

This because you are associating a `Employer` object and saving the `User`. Instead of using `user.save()`, use `user.worker.save()`. This won't create any object for `Employer`.

```
#views.py
def worker_sign_up(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = WorkerSignUpForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()  #save the user
            user.worker = Collector()  # not sure why you need this
            user.worker.address= form.cleaned_data.get('address')

            user.worker.save()  # this will create an object for Worker only

            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = WorkerSignUpForm()
    return render(request, 'registration/workersignup.html', {'form': form})
```

Also, you need to make the `OneToOne` field as optional.

```
# models.py
class Worker(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
)


class Employer(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=400)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True
)
```

Comment: still creates both 'employer' and 'worker' in databse.

Comment: Still not working. It seems 'employer' is creates on `user = form.save()`

Comment: Might be possible. Can you share your form as well?